# Request for help with solving a tricky Riccati Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Long story short, I'm working through a model derivation right now and have arrived at a tricky Riccati Differential Equation that I am afraid has pushed me beyond the limits of my talent. The equation is as follows:

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=c\left(\frac{1-\exp(ht)}{1-g\exp(ht)}\right)+bE+aE^{2}.$$

It seems to me that this can't really be reduced down to an auxiliary equation form as would be the case if the $c$ term was constant, and I don't see any tricks with substitution that would help my cause. I have a strong feeling that I am missing something here. I would greatly appreciate if someone would please help me with this; and additionally if you can point me in the right direction,  please provide a further reference that I may investigate in case I have a case like this in the future.

Thank you!

Edit: I have substituted $h$ for $d$ inside the exponentials, in order to avoid confusion with the differential. Also, $a$, $b$, $c$, $g$, and $h$ are all constants.

Comment: That’s $\exp(d \cdot t)$.

Comment: Also LutzL: I‘ve edited the equation now to replace the $d$s in the exponential with $h$ such that $ht$ are is a multiplication expression.